# NFS COMMIT operation not being invoked despite fsync being used

Tags: linux, rhel, nfs

I have been doing some elaborate testing to determine if our NetApp NFS (v3 protocol) server in `async` mode properly honors the client's `fsync` request. I've hit a wall when I discovered that Linux (RHEL 6, kernel 2.6.32-431.5.1) never issues a COMMIT op at all!!! That fact was uncovered by use of both the `nfsstat` tool, and by the `nfstrace` [tool](https://github.com/epam/nfstrace). Not a single COMMIT.

This seems to violate [NFS semantics](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/):

> Version 3 clients use COMMIT operations when flushing safe asynchronous writes to the server during a close(2) or fsync(2) system call, or when encountering memory pressure.

#### What is going on?

Notes:

The mountpoint is definitely mounted with the async operation (which is the default).

To generate fsync requests, I used Postgresql's `test_fsync` tool. It uses a variety of ways to issue syncs and reports on the benchmarks so you can determine which is best for you on your system.

Timing differences with `test_fsync` indicate the fsync function takes longer to execute on `async` mounts than `sync` mounts, presumably because with `sync` mounts, data is being flushed all the time, and it's only when `fsync` is called that the data is flushed. However, the timing differences is quite erratic and I might just be encountering performance transience.

Mounting the server with the `sync` option changed nothing.

UPDATE: The plot thickens.

On Ubuntu/Mint 17, Linux kernel 3.13.0, (nfs version: 1.2.8), i set up a loopback mountpoint, with both sync and async options and re-ran the tests. Speed differences definitely show a difference between sync and async. `nfsstat` shows that after each run of `pg_fsync_test`, exactly **1** COMMIT transpired.

#### W.T.F.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague at work dug up a possible answer:

> the Netapp technical report tr-3183 (Using Red Hat Client  with NetApp Storage over NFS) says:
>
> > Data ONTAP's NFS server promotes all write requests to FILE_SYNC, whether the client requests UNSTABLE, DATA_SYNC or FILE_SYNC writes. Thus the client never has to send a COMMIT request when it is writing to NetApp storage because all the writes are logged in the NVRAM and the clients get an acknowledgement for the writes right away. Hence the writes with NetApp storage are asynchronous in nature and are much faster.